# In macOS 11.6.8, how do I change the background in Terminal to be a picture file?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, preferences

Suppose I head to Terminal -> Preferences -> Window. I see no option enabling the setting of my Terminal background to be an arbitrary jpg. Further, if I go to such, then type <kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>I</kbd>, once again, no option pops up to enable that.

Is terminal app on macOS 11.6.8 able to place a picture as the background of a command line window?

Answer (score 3):

Can't vouch for 11.6.8, but in 12.5.1 it's in `Terminal | Preferences | Text | Image`. Can't imagine it's changed much since Big Sur.

Note that it only takes effect for a new tab or window, but oddly it will change a window that already has an image to a new one immediately.

Comment: thanks very much for this reply -checking to see if this works now.

Comment: Hope it works for you. Feel free to accept the answer if so...